# Language drop-down not setting culture correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I was working on this nice we language selector but it doesnt appear to be firing the method when I am selecting the new language.

This is inside a partial view in asp.net core 3.1

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options

@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
@inject IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> LocOptions

@{
    var cultureItems = LocOptions.Value.SupportedUICultures
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Name, Text = c.NativeName })
        .ToList();
    var returnUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.Request.Path) ? "~/" : $"~{Context.Request.Path.Value}";
}

<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="languageDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        @Localizer["Language"]
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="languageDropdown">
        @foreach (var language in @cultureItems)
        {
            <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-culture="@language.Value" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl">@language.Text</a>
        }
    </div>
</li>
```

[image]
It generates the following select but it's not getting to the route in my home controller which is the following method. And its going back to the default my set language method is as follows as per other so

```
public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
{
  Response.Cookies.Append(
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
);

  return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

This is my default route path maybe that is the problem

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();

});
```

I use the following to configure the languages in the startup.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   var supportedCultures = new string[] { "en-GB", "fr-FR" };
   app.UseRequestLocalization(options =>
   options
     .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
     .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures)
     .SetDefaultCulture("en-gb")
     .RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new CustomRequestCultureProvider(context =>
 {
    return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult("en-gb"));
  }))
        );
```

**Update Note**
I changed to the following based on the documentation however it's still not setting the culture its always en-GB after the drop-down value selection. I am using this documentation.

It is now firing the correct method.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#implement-a-strategy-to-select-the-languageculture-for-each-request

```
<div title="@Localizer["Request culture provider:"] @requestCulture?.Provider?.GetType().Name">
    <form id="selectLanguage" asp-controller="Home" 
          asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl" 
          method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <label asp-for="@requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name">@Localizer["Language:"]</label> <select name="culture"
          onchange="this.form.submit();"
          asp-for="@requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name" asp-items="cultureItems">
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Update 2**
I also saw that cookie concent might be the issue but it's still not saving even if I comment out this line out of my startup.

```
 services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
      //   options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
```

**Update 3** 
Ok So I have got it saving the cookie and it's putting the value correctly in according to the developer tools in chrome. But its still putting the english version of the text on screen.

[image]

Comment: `I have got it saving the cookie and it's putting the value correctly in according to the developer tools in chrome. But its still putting the english version of the text on screen.` Please check if you provided and named [resource file(s)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#resource-files) correctly.

Comment: You are inserting the custom culture provider at the beginning of the providers list, so it is always returning "en-gb" without checking other providers. Try insert it at different index `.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(2, new CustomRequestCultureProvider)` or use add `.RequestCultureProviders.Add(new Custom...)`

Answer (score 0):

How is your `CustomRequestCultureProvider` setting the culture?

Do you want to your custom provider or use cookies or route value to set the culture? or all of them in a specific order?

---

In the default implementation of your custom provider try change the return value to something else and check the result:

```cs
return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult("en-gb"));
```

most probably the custom culture provider is always returning "en-gb" so it not checking the cookie or route value for request culture.

---

In the language dropdown you have `asp-route-culture`:

```html
<a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-culture="@language.Value" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl">@language.Text</a>
```

but you don't have `{route}` parameter in the route pattern:

```cs
pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
```

So try adding the `{culture}` to the route pattern:

```cs
pattern: "{culture=en-gb}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
```

Comment: It is already returning a task item please re read it carefully
    return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult("en-gb"));